# How to delete triangles from an openmesh without creating polygons?

Tags: openmesh

When I call `mesh.delete_face(face_handle)` in an OpenMesh using `OpenMesh::TriMesh_ArrayKernelT<>` I get somehow faces with more than 3 vertices, possibly a polygon around the hole created by deleted faces.

How can I avoid this to just get a boundary around the hole but no polygon? I am a bit surprised that a TriMesh can contain polygonal faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling garbage collection fixes this.

I am a bit surprised as I would have thought you need to call garbage collection after removing and adding faces so you do not delete intermediate configurations possibly losing some objects your handles are pointing to.